# Managed C++ unresolved token

Tags: managed-c++

I'm new to managed C++.

I have two managed C++ projects in a single .sln, Project Lib and Project LibTest. LibTest makes use of Lib.

Lib compiles and links fine. The project is set as a .dll.

LibTest is also compiled as .dll, but when it goes into linking, I get "unresolved token" on all of the Lib::methods. Those methods definitions are defined in the Lib .cpp file.

If I moved the definitions into the Lib.h file, everything works.

I have already modified LibTest's Reference to depend on Lib project.

What am I missing?

**EDIT**: Okay here's exactly what I have and it still doesn't work.

First off, I'm using Visual Studio 2008 SP1.

Secondly, when I did a similar exercise in C#, it worked fine.

I created an empty C++ CLR project. I added a Lib project. I added a managed class. VSTD generated Lib.h and Lib.cpp. The constructor is automatically generated.

Then I added another project to my solution; I called it LibTest. I added another managed class called LibTest. LibTest.h and LibTest.cpp are generated. I tried to instantiate Lib in LibTest constructor, but during linking it simply said:

1>LibTest.obj : error LNK2020: unresolved token (06000002) Lib::.ctor

Here's the exact code:

**Lib Project (compiled as .dll project)**

```
//Lib.h
#pragma once

ref class Lib
{
public:
  Lib(void);
};


//Lib.cpp
#include "Lib.h"

Lib::Lib(void)
{
}
```

**LibTest Project (compiled as application.exe)**

```
// LibTest.h
#pragma once

ref class LibTest
{
public:
  LibTest(void);
};

// LibTest.cpp
#include "LibTest.h"
#include "Lib.h"

LibTest::LibTest(void)
{
  Lib^ lib = gcnew Lib;
}

int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow..I must say..coming from unmanaged C++..I have ALWAYS wanted the development environment (in this case the VSTD IDE) to manage the #include, and all the library linking without me having to explicitly specify it. This is pretty amazing! I wish to tell the whole unmanaged C++ world of this! (I'm only 6 years behind! =p)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Managed C++ works just like C# regarding types in different assemblies. What this means is that you need to declare your `Lib` class as `public`:

```
public ref class Lib
```

And you should not include `Lib.h` in your `LibTest` project. When you add the reference to the `Lib` project, the compiler will be able to resolve any symbols found there.

Your current code includes `Lib.h`, and so the linker searches for the `Lib` class in the `LibTest` assembly and looks for the constructor there.

Comment: Thank you, Bojan; problem solved. I wish I could have voted for you 10 times..but stackoverflow only allows 1. ;-)

Comment: Anytime - I'm glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using managed extensions, setting the reference correctly should be all you need.

If you're using standard C++ functions, you probably need to define your functions using `__declspec(dllexport)` and `__declspec(dllimport)`.  [See MSDN for details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a90k134d.aspx).

`__declspec(dllexport)` is what adds specific functions into the export library, and `__declspec(dllimport)` tells the importing library (LibTest) that it needs to import those symbols from the DLL.

Answer (score 1):

In  project LibTest, property->Configuration properties->Linker->Input->set Additional Dependecies, include Lib.lib

Answer (score 0):

Here's the final modification as proposed by Bojan. Thanks Bojan!

Note: dont't forget to add "Lib" to your "LibTest" Reference!

**Lib Project (compiled as .dll project)**

//Lib.h

```
#pragma once

public ref class Lib
{
public:
  Lib(void);
};
```

//Lib.cpp

```
#include "Lib.h"

Lib::Lib(void)
{
}
```

**LibTest Project (compiled as application.exe)**

// LibTest.h

```
#pragma once

ref class LibTest
{
public:
  LibTest(void);
};
```

// LibTest.cpp

```
#include "LibTest.h"

LibTest::LibTest(void)
{
  Lib^ lib = gcnew Lib;
}

int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```